# Pass Windows Identity to SSRS Report Custom Data Source

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, datasource, reportviewer, ssrs-2012

I am new to world of SSRS Reports and am facing some issues trying to connect to my DataSource.

I have created a new datasource with following properties

- Use a connection embedded in my report
- Connection Type : Microsoft SQL Server
- Connection String : [@ConnectionString] , Where @ConnectionString is name of my report parameter.

In Credentials Tab

- Prompt for credentials (with checkbox for 'Use as Windows Credentials' unchecked)

I am using this datasource to prepopulate my report's dropdown control with available values in DB.
Now, the scenario is I am going to pass connection string from my aspx page to SSRS report viewer .

Code excerpt below:

```
this.rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote; 
this.rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(reportServerUrl);//https                
this.rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
// this can have either UserName & Password specified or have IntegratedSecurity=SSPI
connStrBuildr.ConnectionString = connStr; 
ReportParameter reportParameter = new ReportParameter("ConnectionString", connStrBuildr.ConnectionString, false);
this.rptViewer.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
this.rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameter);                                    

if (!connStrBuildr.IntegratedSecurity) { // for SQL Auth
   this.rptViewer.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(new List<DataSourceCredentials>() { 
       new DataSourceCredentials() {
         Name = "Custom_DataSource",
         UserId = connStrBuildr.UserID,
         Password = connStrBuildr.Password } });
 }
 else // for Windows Auth 
  { 
     // Created a new class as per some suggestion on internet, to connect to ReportServer which inturn will pass window identity to SQL Server,
     // but even this didn't work - had no way to exact password . MIND BLOWING STUFF !! 

     //rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new CustomReportCredential(username,password,domain)

   }
this.rptViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

My requirement is 
If my connection string has username and password specified, then those should be used to connect with the SQL (Custom_DataSource).

If IntegratedSecurity=SSPI is specified , it should use Windows Authentication to connect with the SQL (Custom_DataSource).

I have tried creating derived class

```
CustomReportCredential:Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials
```

but even that didn't work out. Modifying web.config to Keep Impersonate (true/false), and many similar. None of them worked out.

Present Scenario:
If i change report to use **Windows integrated security**, all my Windows Authentication enabled connection string run properly, but fails for the one's that has UserName and Password specified.

And vice-versa, if i change report to use **Prompt for credentials**(with checkbox for 'Use as Windows Credentials' unchecked).

Expected :

- How can i allow both methods (Windows/SQL) of connection to DataSource ?

This might be a trivial scenario but I am unable to find proper solution to it.

Any help or pointers will be most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I found this looking for a different answer about a similar scenario. In mine, though, I'm setting rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials to a windows account that has access to the report. Without that, it makes no difference what I supply as a connection string, the application can't even access the report. I see this is old, but was that perhaps your problem? I'm just wondering if the connection string is any more at risk of compromise if its passed to the report using parameters, and also if there is a better option than having to storing an AD account and password in the web.config in order for the ReportViewer to have access to the report.